# How to get current date time – date() and calender()

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, date-arithmetic

I want hours and minutes will start from the current date will be October 10, 2016 end of days

```
package com.mkyong.date;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateDifferentExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        //get current date time with Date()
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
        //get current date time with Calendar()
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
        String dateStart = "01/14/2012 09:29:58";
        String dateStop = "01/15/2012 10:31:48";
        //HH converts hour in 24 hours format (0-23), day calculation
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date d1 = null;
        Date d2 = null;
        try
        {
            d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
            d2 = format.parse(dateStop);
            //in milliseconds
            long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
            long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
            long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
            long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
            long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            System.out.print(diffDays + " days, ");
            System.out.print(diffHours + " hours, ");
            System.out.print(diffMinutes + " minutes, ");
            System.out.print(diffSeconds + " seconds.");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Results :

```
2016/08/15 18:54:03
2016/08/15 18:54:03
1097 Days1 Hours 1 Minute 50 Second 
My want to result for example :
100 days 5 hours 2 minutes
```

Answer (score 3):

## Avoid old date-time classes

You are using troublesome old legacy date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. Use java.time classes instead.

## Parsing

Your input strings are almost in standard ISO 8601 format. Replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`. The java.time classes parse/generate strings using ISO 8601 formats by default. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String startInput = "01/14/2012 09:29:58".replace( " " , "T" );
String stopInput = "01/15/2012 10:31:48".replace( " " , "T" );
```

### `LocalDateTime`

Your inputs lack any information about offset-from-UTC or time zone. So we parse as `LocalDateTime` objects.

```
LocalDateTime startLdt = LocalDateTime.parse( startInput );
LocalDateTime stopLdt = LocalDateTime.parse( stopInput );
```

If you work further with these types you will get results based on generic 24-hour days while ignoring anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

If you know the context of this data is a particular time zone, apply the zone to get `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime start = startLdt.atZone( zoneId );
ZonedDateTime stop = stopLdt.atZone( zoneId );
```

If you want the current moment as the start or the stop, call `now`. Pass the desired/expected time zone rather than relying on the JVM’s current default time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );
```

## Duration

The [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class represents a span of time as a total of seconds plus a fraction of a second in nanoseconds resolution.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( start , stop );
```

Oddly, in Java 8 this class lacks methods to get the number of days, hours, etc. making up this span of time. Java 9 [adds `to…Part` methods](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8142936).

```
long days = duration.toDaysPart();
int hours = duration.toHoursPart();
int minutes = duration.toMinutesPart();
```

Until Java 9 you can do the math yourself.

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.

Answer (score 1):

**public final void set(int year,int month,int date)** - this method of Calendar class can be used to set date .

**public final void set(int year, int month,int date,int hourOfDay,int minute,int second)** can be used to set time too.

**Calendar.getInstance()** by default set current date and time.`